# How can I remove the grid line in the background of the property shape chart?

Tags: reactjs, plot, plotly

I am working on a React JS project. In my project, I need to create line chart components. I am trying to use [React Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/react/) library for React JS. I made a few changes to the shape property to show a different color array for each sniper data.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h62y3.png)

This is my code

```
export const convertListIc = [{
layer: "below",
x0: 0,
y0: 0,
x1: 1.31,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "black",
opacity: 0.6,},{
layer: "below",
x0: 1.31,
y0: 0,
x1: 2.05,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "grey",
opacity: 0.6,},{
layer: "below",
x0: 2.05,
y0: 0,
x1: 2.6,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "green",
opacity: 0.6,},{
layer: "below",
x0: 2.6,
y0: 0,
x1: 2.95,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "yellow",
opacity: 0.6,},{
layer: "below",
x0: 2.95,
y0: 0,
x1: 3.06,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "red",
opacity: 0.6, },{
layer: "below",
x0: 3.06,
y0: 0,
x1: 4.0,
y1: 1,
type: "rect",
xref: "x",
yref: "paper",
fillcolor: "brown",
opacity: 0.6,},];
```

is there a way to get rid of those black vertical grids between those colored areas?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all grid lines from the background using the following:

```
var data = ...
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
    showgrid: False
     },
    yaxis: {
     showgrid: False
    }
   };

 Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data,layout);
```